# Help with limit $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}\int_{x}^{x+h}P(t, y)\ dt$..

Tags: analysis

Let $D\subseteq \mathbb R^2$ be an open set and $P:D\rightarrow \mathbb R$ continuous.
For $y$ fixed how to evaluate,

$$\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}\int_{x}^{x+h}P(t, y)\ dt?$$

I know the answer, the limit above must be $P(x, y)$ but I can't see why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note first that
$$
\frac{1}{h}\int_x^{x+h}P(t,h)dt-P(x,y)=\frac{1}{h}\int_x^{x+h}(P(t,y)-P(x,y))dt
$$
for all $|h|$ small enough such that $[x,x+h]\times\{y\}$ or $[x+h,x]\times\{y\}$ is contained in $D$.

Fix $\epsilon>0$.

Now by continuity of $t\longmapsto P(t,y)$ at $x$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|P(t,y)-P(x,y)|\leq \epsilon$ for $|h|\leq \delta$.

Then
$$
|\frac{1}{h}\int_x^{x+h}P(t,y)dt-P(x,y)|\leq \frac{1}{|h|}|\int_x^{x+h}|P(t,y)-P(x,y)|dt|\leq \frac{1}{|h|}|h|\epsilon=\epsilon
$$
for all non zero $|h|\leq \delta$.

So
$$
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{h}\int_x^{x+h}P(t,y)dt=P(x,y).
$$